# Plotting user selected images in Shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny

This is my first attempt at creating a Shiny app so I wanted to do something very simple: use `fileInput` so the user can select an image on their computer and then `renderImage` to plot the image.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("plot image"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         fileInput("image",
                     "Select your image:", placeholder = "No file selected")
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("photo")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

     output$photo <- renderImage({
      img <- load.image(input$image) 
      plot(img)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, when I try to load an image with this I get an error: **invalid filename argument**.

Ultimately I would like to integrate `selectInput` the `choices` option would have a few default images as well as those the user uploaded with `fileInput` but I feel that I'm already getting ahead of myself on that.

### UPDATE 1:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(imager)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("plot images"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         fileInput("image",
                     "Select your image:", placeholder = "No file selected")
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("photo")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$photo <- renderPlot({
    # Ensure the values for 'image' are available
    # If not, the operation is stopped by raising a "silent" exception
    req(input$image)
    # Get edges of image with imager::cannyEdges
    img <- cannyEdges(input$image)
    # img is now a logical array with 4 dimensions but we only want 2 - discard two of the dimensions
    img <- img[, , 1, 1]
    # Convert the matrix into a list of coordinates
    coords <- which(img, arr.ind = T)
    # Turn the coordinates into a dataframe
    df <- data.frame(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2])
    # Plot the coordinates
    ggplot(df, aes(x, -y)) +
      geom_point()
      })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If your intent is to render a plot, use `renderPlot()` for the server.

Comment: Yeah that would be what I'm ultimately trying to achieve. The `req` function makes sure a input was actually selected. Then I use edge-detection on that image and transform it to coordinates which are then turned into a dataframe then plotted with ggplot2

Comment: Okay so in the question update I changed `renderImage()` to `renderPlot()` but it doesn't work. For example, If I replace `input$image` with `boats` in the server section (a toy image from the `imager` package) I get the output I want to see; however, it's static and not from the `fileInput` selection

Answer (score 0):

See `?fileInput`. If `"image"` is the id, then the path to the uploaded file is `input$image$datapath`, not `input$image`.

So you can do something like:

```
output$photo <- renderImage({
  req(input$image)
  list(src = input$image$datapath, alt="alternative text")
})
```

and in `ui`,

```
imageOutput("photo")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and solved. the image can't be loaded is because the `input$image` doesn't just give the filename you want, but also give more information. That make it a named list rather than a single value. Maybe you can try as following in your first case.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

     output$photo <- renderImage({
      img <- load.image(input$image[[4]]) 
      plot(img)
   })
}
```

Hope it works.